# How to add each line from string to listbox vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Okay my website is connected to mysql database and it reads off strings of data from the database into plain text. I want to get each line from my website and add it to a list box.

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim GetInfo As String = WBInfo.DownloadString("https://MyWebsite.com/test.php?id=data")
```

GetInfo Outputs Like:
user1:user2:user3
user2:user3:user4
user3:user4:user5
etc..

```
For Each line In GetInfo
    Dim parts As String() = line.ToString.Split(New Char() {":"c})
    ListBox1.Items.Add(parts(1))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(parts(2))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(parts(3))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In first,  use

```
Dim parts As String() = line.ToString.Split(":"c)
```

Note,  the indexes of an array starts from 0. Also you can use `For Each` loop statement instead of indexes,  for example:

```
For Each part As String In parts
    ListBox1.Items.Add(part)
Next
```

To maintain performance while items are added to the ListBox use [BeginUpdate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate(v=vs.110).aspx) and [EndUpdate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.endupdate(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.